# Where can I find ROM images for Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 (GT P5113)?

Tags: cyanogenmod, device-firmware, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10.1

I've stopped using my tablet several years ago out of frustration. Ever since Kit Kat/4.4.4 everything has slowed to a near unusable crawl. I tried rectifying this by flashing it with a SlimRoms OS (SlimKat) but it only improves things moderately and some applications, like YouTube, crash often.

I'm looking to see if maybe Jelly Bean runs better, but so far I've had no luck with it. The Samsung downgraded firmware just puts it into a boot loop and I cannot find a compatible SlimRom, Lineage OS, or Cyanogenmod. Does anyone know if one exists?

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-tab-2

Comment: I've searched most of those sites to no avail. Many dead links and the only available ROM seems to be SlimKat. 
@AndyYan Your link does not have links to any ROM other than SlimKat.

Comment: The "unified" have up-to-date ROMs.